# Update Jenkins running on docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, registry

I have a Jenkins running on Docker container and local docker registry. 
`docker-compose up` 
it does't go out side network rather pulls the image from local registry.

Is there a way i can update my local docker registry with latest Jenkins image?

And when i run `docker-compose up` i have latest Jenkins? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So by default docker nature is always look for image available on host-machine and if not specific tag is provided it will search for default tag which is `latest` .

So in your case when you already have latest jenkins image available on host `docker-compose` will always use that image pretending this is the latest one. For using latest image available from registry you need to clean/delete jenkins image from your host who is having `latest` tag.

Delete and use latest jenkins image:

```
docker rmi -f jenkins:latest
docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm -f
docker-compose pull   
docker-compose up -d
```

this is your private registry so you need to login to it:
`docker login my-server.test:5000`

Comment: Thanks anand, 
I did exactly what you said. But the problem is my jenkins doesn't upgrade to the latest version. Rather it pulls from the local registry. This is what i have inside my host docker-compose

`Jenkins:
  image: my-server.test:5000/jenkins-stable`

Comment: looks like this is your private registry, have you done `docker login` first on this registry server ?

Comment: Yes, it is a private docker registry. No i have not done `docker login`

Comment: instead of first 3 commands, you can just type "docker-compose down"